# Recover the source code from the pdf file

Tags: pdf, sourcecode

Recently, I lost most of my drive content, and now I've succeed to retrieve my Curriculum_Vitae.pdf. I have a little problem if I want to modify this file, because I don't have the source code anymore. Is there exists a way to recover or to reload that source code from the pdf file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unless you went out of your way to artificially place the source code inside the PDF document, my strong suspicion is "not possible".

Comment: No. The text can usually be extracted (pdftotext, copy&paste, ...), but the markup of the source file is lost.

Comment: Ok, thanks to both of you. I will recreate this file

Comment: ... and back your work up in the future!

Comment: I backed up all my works, but I did a stupid thing (bootable my external drive where my back-up was installed)